# Java, rock paper scissor program not working properly

Tags: java

These are the instructions for this program...

"**Step 1** Read two player names from input (String). Read number of rounds from input. Continue reading number of rounds if value is below one and provide an error message. Output player names and number of rounds. Submit for grading to confirm 2 tests pass.

**Step 2.** Generate random values (0 - 2) for player 1 followed by player 2 by calling `rand.nextInt(3)`. Continue to generate random values for both players until both values do not match. Output "Tie" when the values match. Submit for grading to confirm 3 tests pass.

**Step 3.** Identify winner for this round and output a message. Rock crushes scissors, scissors cut paper, and paper covers rock. Submit for grading to confirm 6 tests pass.

**Step 4.** Add a loop to repeat steps 2 and 3 for the number of rounds. Output total wins for each player after all rounds are complete. Submit for grading to confirm all tests pass."

why am I getting a different output than expected...

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;

public class LabProgram {
public static void main(String[] args) {
  Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);
  final int ROCK = 0;
  final int PAPER = 1;
  final int SCISSORS = 2;
  Random rand = new Random();
  int seed = scnr.nextInt();
  rand.setSeed(seed);
  
  /* Insert your code here */
  String player1;
  String player2;
  int numOfRounds;
  
  player1 = scnr.next();
  player2 = scnr.next();
  numOfRounds = scnr.nextInt();
  
  while (numOfRounds < 1) { 
     System.out.println("Rounds must be > 0");
     numOfRounds = scnr.nextInt();
     }
  System.out.println(player1 + " vs " + player2 + " for " + numOfRounds + " rounds");

  int p1wins = 0;
  int p2wins = 0; 
  
  
  for (int i = 0; i <= numOfRounds+1; ++i) {
     int p1 = rand.nextInt(3);
     int p2 = rand.nextInt(3);
     if (p1 == p2) {
        System.out.println("Tie");
     }
     else if (p1 == 0 && p2 == 1) {
     System.out.println(player2 + " wins with paper");
     p2wins+=1;
        }
     else if (p1 == 0 && p2 == 2) {
     System.out.println(player1 + " wins with rock");
     p1wins+=1;
        }
     else if (p1 == 1 && p2 == 0) {
     System.out.println(player1 + " wins with paper");
     p1wins+=1;
        }
     else if (p1 == 1 && p2 == 2) {
     System.out.println(player2 + " wins with scissors");
     p2wins+=1;
        }
     else if (p1 == 2 && p2 == 0) {
     System.out.println(player2 + " wins with rock");
     p2wins+=1;
        }
     else if (p1 == 2 && p2 == 1) {
     System.out.println(player1 + " wins with scissors");
     p1wins+=1;
     }
  }
  
  if(p1wins < p2wins)
  System.out.println(player2 + " wins " + p2wins + " and " + player1 + " wins " + p1wins);
  else if(p2wins < p1wins)
  System.out.println(player1 + " wins " + p1wins + " and " + player2 + " wins " + p2wins);
 }

}
```

Input:

```
17 Randy Jenny 15
```

My Output:

```
Randy wins with paper
Randy wins with paper
Randy wins with paper
Randy wins with paper
Randy wins with paper
Tie
Randy wins with paper
Jenny wins with scissors
Jenny wins with rock
Randy wins with rock
Jenny wins with scissors
Tie
Randy wins with rock
Jenny wins with paper
Tie
Randy wins 8 and Jenny wins 5
```

Expected Output:

```
Randy wins with rock
Jenny wins with paper
Tie
Tie
Jenny wins with paper
Tie
Randy wins with paper
Randy wins 9 and Jenny wins 6
```

Comment: do not post pictures of code and output, put them as formatted text instead

Comment: I apologize, I was not very sure..I edited it

Comment: You posted your expected output, what's the actual output?

Comment: Why would you expect this output?

Comment: The expected output is output from my assignment...every other test passed, only this one is different

Comment: I wonder the expected output: sum of wins 9+6 = 15, but it should have played 15 rounds and there are some ties - is the code supposed to not count the ties as a round? ("*Continue to generate random values for both players until both values do not match.*") || **and** `i <= numOfRounds+1` cannot be right

Comment: if the ties do not count as a round.. it does not make sense with the expected output that my assignment provided.. everything was working until step 4 where I had to put a loop for steps 2 and 3

Comment: you are violating the requirements of step 2: "Continue to generate random values for both players until both values do not match.". So you need a loop inside the outer loop, that ends when the random values for both players do not match.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Several issues with your code, going through it:

```java
String player1;
String player2;
int numOfRounds;
  
player1 = scnr.next();
player2 = scnr.next();
numOfRounds = scnr.nextInt();
```

Here it would increase readability if you merged declaration and initial assignment:

```java
String player1 = scnr.next();
String player2 = scnr.next();
int numOfRounds = scnr.nextInt();
```

---

```java
for (int i = 0; i <= numOfRounds+1; ++i) {
```

This will loop two times too much, if you enter 15 for the number of rounds, `i` will go from 0 to 16, which is 17 entries into the loop - two to much.
correct would be:

```java
for (int i = 0; i < numOfRounds; ++i) {
```

---

```java
int p1 = rand.nextInt(3);
int p2 = rand.nextInt(3);
if (p1 == p2) {
   System.out.println("Tie");
}
```

This does count a "Tie" also a round, which the expected output clearly does not support (also the instruction of step 2)
Correct would be a loop until a winner can be found (both random values are not equal):

```java
int p1 = rand.nextInt(3);
int p2 = rand.nextInt(3);
while (p1 == p2) {
  System.out.println("Tie");
  p1 = rand.nextInt(3);
  p2 = rand.nextInt(3);
}
```

With more refactoring your code could get even better read- and reusable (extracting code into reusable methodes etc.) but first you should get it running correctly.

Answer (score 0):

First of all I would decompose the code with a parts. It's better to encapsulate `win/lost` logic within separate class e.g. `enum Tool`.

```java
public class Foo {

    public static void main(String... args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        Random random = new Random();

        String p1 = getPlayerName(scan, 1);
        String p2 = getPlayerName(scan, 2);
        int totalRounds = getTotalRounds(scan);

        System.out.format("%s vs %s for %d rounds\n", p1, p2, totalRounds);

        int p1wins = 0;
        int p2wins = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < totalRounds; i++) {
            Tool p1Tool = Tool.random(random);
            Tool p2Tool = Tool.random(random);
            String res;

            if (p1Tool == p2Tool) {
                res = "Tie";
            } else if (p1Tool.isWinner(p2Tool)) {
                res = p1 + " wins";
                p1wins++;
            } else {
                res = p2 + " wins";
                p2wins++;
            }

            System.out.format("Round %d: %s (%s) vs %s (%s) - %s\n", i + 1,
                              p1, p1Tool.getName(), p2, p2Tool.getName(), res);
        }

        System.out.println("---");
        System.out.format("%s (%d) vs %s (%d) - %s\n", p1, p1wins, p2, p2wins,
                          p1wins == p2wins ? "Tie" : (p1wins > p2wins ? p1 : p2) + " wins");
    }

    private static String getPlayerName(Scanner scan, int i) {
        System.out.format("Enter player %d name: ", i);
        return scan.next();
    }

    private static int getTotalRounds(Scanner scan) {
        int res = 0;

        while (res <= 0) {
            System.out.print("Enter total rounds: ");
            res = scan.nextInt();
        }

        return res;
    }

    @Getter
    @RequiredArgsConstructor(access = AccessLevel.PACKAGE)
    private enum Tool {
        ROCK("rock", "scissors"),
        PAPER("paper", "rock"),
        SCISSORS("scissors", "paper");

        private final String name;
        private final String nameWin;

        public final boolean isWinner(Tool tool) {
            return nameWin.equals(tool.name);
        }

        public static Tool random(Random random) {
            int id = random.nextInt(3);
            return id == 0 ? ROCK : id == 1 ? PAPER : SCISSORS;
        }
    }

}
```